# Basic Fourier Analysis question -- Don't understand a theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've been studying solving **homogeneous heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions** and on the notes I encounter Fourier analysis, which I haven't figure out yet. (The notes are here)[Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0azd.png)

One thing I'm not sure about is that, if any function (such as f(x) = x) that satisfies the hypothesis can be approximated with an infinite sine series (sin(mπx)), for the Fourier expansion of f(x) = x with sin(mπx), when x = 1, any sin(mπx) will rigorously equal to 0, how can the summation of infinite 0 be 1?

This keeps annoying me to doubt whether I fully understand the theorem on the notes.

Comment: The theorem doesn't say that the series converges to $f$ at every point.

Comment: Oh, I see! So the theorem actually describes that the series can converge to f in a certain interval with respect to L2 norm, and a divergence on a certain point ( like x = 1 ) won't affect this result due to the property of integration.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich
ok! I still have a further question to ask. I encounter a question asking me to prove$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} ||u(t,x) - x||_{L^2([0, 1])} = 0   -----(1)
$$
where
$$
u(t,x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+1}e^{-m^2\pi^2t}\frac{2}{m\pi}sin(m\pi x)
$$ And in case you recalculate this, $$u(0, x)$$is the fourier expansion with sine series of $$f(x) = x$$. But it seems that I can substitute t in $$u(t, x)$$ directly with 0 and prove (1) instantly with theorem in the note saying the $$u(0, x)$$ is the Fourier expansion of x on [0, 1]. I'm not sure whether this proof is rigorous.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich
I just don't get what this question asks me to accomplish.